# How to override Django admin `change_list.html` to provide formatting on the go

Tags: django, django-templates

In Django admin, if I want to display a list of `Iron` and their respective formatted weights, I would have to do this.

```
class IronAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Iron
    fields = ('weight_formatted',)

def weight_formatted(self, object):
    return '{0:.2f} Kg'.format(object.weight)
weight_formatted.short_description = 'Weight'

I.e: 500.00 Kg
```

The problem with this however is that I would have to write a method for every field that I want to format, making it redundant when I have 10 or more objects to format.

Is there a method that I could override to "catch" these values and specify formatting before they get rendered onto the html? I.e. instead of having to write a method for each Admin class, I could just write the following and have it be formatted.

```
class IronAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Iron
    fields = ('weight__kg',)

def overriden_method(field):
    if field.name.contains('__kg'):
        field.value = '{0:.2f} Kg'.format(field.value)

I.e: 500.00 Kg
```

Answer (score 1):

After hours scouring the source , I finally figured it out! I realize this isn't the most efficient code and it's probably more trouble than it's worth in most use cases but it's enough for me. In case anyone else needs a quick and dirty way to do it:

In order to automate it, I had to override `django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list.result_list` with the following:

```
def result_list_larz(cl):
    """
    Displays the headers and data list together
    """
    resultz = list(results(cl))  # Where we override

    """ Overriding starts here """
    """ Have to scrub the __kg's as result_header(cl) will error out """
    for k in cl.list_display:
        cl.list_display[cl.list_display.index(k)] = k.replace('__kg','').replace('__c','')
    headers = list(result_headers(cl))

    num_sorted_fields = 0
    for h in headers:
        if h['sortable'] and h['sorted']:
            num_sorted_fields += 1
    return {'cl': cl,
            'result_hidden_fields': list(result_hidden_fields(cl)),
            'result_headers': headers,
            'num_sorted_fields': num_sorted_fields,
            'results': resultz}
```

Then overriding `results(cl)`'s call to `items_for_result()` wherein we then override its call to `lookup_field()` as follows:

```
def lookup_field(name, obj, model_admin=None):
opts = obj._meta
try:
    f = _get_non_gfk_field(opts, name)
except (FieldDoesNotExist, FieldIsAForeignKeyColumnName):
    # For non-field values, the value is either a method, property or
    # returned via a callable.
    if callable(name):
        attr = name
        value = attr(obj)
    elif (model_admin is not None and
            hasattr(model_admin, name) and
            not name == '__str__' and
            not name == '__unicode__'):
        attr = getattr(model_admin, name)
        value = attr(obj)

    """ Formatting code here """
    elif '__kg' in name or '__c' in name:  # THE INSERT FOR FORMATTING!

        actual_name = name.replace('__kg','').replace('__c', '')
        value = getattr(obj, actual_name)
        value = '{0:,.2f}'.format(value)

        prefix = ''
        postfix = ''
        if '__kg' in name:
            postfix = ' Kg'
        elif '__c' in name:
            prefix = 'P'

        value = '{}{}{}'.format(prefix, value, postfix)
        attr = value
    else:
        attr = getattr(obj, name)
        if callable(attr):
            value = attr()
        else:
            value = attr
    f = None
    """ Overriding code END """

else:
    attr = None
    value = getattr(obj, name)
return f, attr, value
```